# My Nexus 7 became slower after the update to 4.2. How can I fix it?

Tags: nexus-7, 4.2-jelly-bean

After the update to android 4.2 my nexus 7 became slower.

Switching applications takes some seconds and even the menu that pop-ups after I push the 'share' button takes a while to appear.

Is there something I can do to have its performance back to the usual level?

Comment: I had the same problem, and noticed that "prey" (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prey) seemed to be using more CPU than I expected.  I uninstalled it, and things _might_ be a bit faster now.

Comment: @offby1 how can I track the CPU usage of my applications?
I don't have Prey installed, so it may be another application that is still not fully compatible with Android 4.2.
In my case it may be [Set orientation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5nb29nbGVjb2RlLmV5ZXNmcmVlLnNldG9yaWVudGF0aW9uIl0.) that sometimes crashes, but I'd like to be sure before saying that it is the culprit

Comment: * Swipe down from the upper-right, to display the 3x3 grid of shortcuts

* Tap "Settings"

* Tap "Apps"

* Swipe left to look at the "Running" column

* Examine the numbers in the right column -- they tell you how much CPU time the app has racked up.  Look for really big numbers :-)

Comment: I don't get the display of that 'running' window... There is always a letter in front of the numbers, e.g. F3:54:15. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all updates, the first thing that comes to mind is factory resetting the device. This clears all the remnants of the old version out of the system and resets app data that could cause inconsistencies. The downside is you'll lose all your apps and their data.

Normally I only do a factory reset in between major versions (3.2->4.0, 4.0.2->4.1 etc.), but if minor updates cause trouble, this would be a first step for me.

Oh yeah, the reset can be found in `Settings -> Backup & reset -> Factory data reset`. Note that while this usually doesn't affect your sdcard (including internal storage), some devices may wipe that too. But not the Nexus series, so you're safe.

Comment: Is there any drawback in factory resetting the device?
Am I going to lose any setting of they are not affected?

Comment: Yes, it will clear your settings if they are not synced to Google's backup, your installed apps and their data. Basically it will be just like when you first started using it, except that the internal storage will not be cleared.

Comment: Is Google's backup enabled by default?

Comment: I can't remember, but you can see it in the `Backup & reset` section of `Settings` (`Backup my data`)

Comment: I just did it, and I figured out that it didn't restore the applications I placed in the home screen nor the accounts I was logged into. It is not a problem to me but I feel that is is worth saying

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was implied by "The downside is you'll lose all your apps and their data" and "Basically it will be just like when you first started using it[...]".

Comment: Don't worry. I still have to stress test it, but it seems faster, so it has been worth it.

Comment: I believe that Google's backup is on by default, but I also believe that it doesn't work well.  Expect to lose everything.